# MVC DataAnnotations should accept decimal without zero

Tags: regex, model-view-controller, data-annotations

Below is my DataAnnotations

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((\d+)((\.\d{1,4})?))$", ErrorMessage = "PartSize must be numeric / 4 digit decimal")]
```

It accepts 0.52 but denies .52!

What can be added to that validator?

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick:

```
(?=[\d\.])(?'number'\d*(\.\d{1,4})?)
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/Pg4GPd/1).

The main trick is that I changed `\d+` to `\d*` for capturing the first digit (allows for the integer part to be missing).

I added the look-ahead to remove the zero-length matches.